# Robocopy didn't recognize options when launched from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I'm trying to use the PowerShell cmdlet `Invoke-Expression` to launch RoboCopy.

In the script below, RoboCopy worked fine when the option was simply '*.*' but as soon as the option '/MIR' was added I got this "Invalid Parameter #3" error.

It seems that RoboCopy is having problems parsing '/MIR' and has choked on the forward slash in the option. I've tried using all sort of escaping characters to no avail!

```
# Source & Destination paths
#
  [string]$srcPath = 'C:\folderSrc'
  [string]$desPath = 'C:\folderDes'

# Example 1
# ----------
# This works - note how $option1 contains only '*.*'
#
  [string]$option1 = '*.*'
  [string]$line = 'RoboCopy  $srcPath  $desPath  $option1'
  Invoke-Expression "$line"

# Example 2:
# ----------
# This doesn't work - after '/MIR' is added to the option, RoboCopy seems to choke on the forward slash in '/MIR'
#
  [string]$option2 = '*.* /MIR'
  [string]$line = 'RoboCopy  $srcPath  $desPath  $option2'
  Invoke-Expression "$line"
```

Comment: In my question, example 1 works, but example 2 did not. and the only difference is $option1 = '\*.\*'    and    $option2 = '\*.\*  /MIR'

Comment: I don't think there was an variable expansion problem because example 1 would not work if the variables did not get expanded properly

Comment: First, please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42496558/edit), don't add comments to try and modify it. Second, with the knowledge that this is an interpreter and not straight PowerShell, as shared in your response to the answer by Christopher G. Lewis, I would think that this is an issue with your interpreter and not PowerShell itself. It would appear that the interpreter is not handling the slash correctly.

Comment: the operator to stop parsing might be of use to you here: --% https://ss64.com/ps/stop-parsing.html

Answer (score 1):

I found that this (using double InvokeExpression) worked:

```
  [string]$srcPath = 'C:\folderSrc'
  [string]$desPath = 'C:\folderDes'
  [string]$option = '*.* /MIR'
  [string]$line = 'Invoke-Expression  "RoboCopy  $srcPath  $desPath  $option"'

  Invoke-Expression "$line"
```

But couldn't explain why this (using single Invoke-Expression) also works:

```
  [string]$srcPath = 'C:\folderSrc'
  [string]$desPath = 'C:\folderDes'
  [string]$option = '*.*'
  [string]$line = 'RoboCopy  $srcPath  $desPath  $option'

  Invoke-Expression "$line"
```

Note that the sole difference in the 2 scenarios is the $option variable:

```
 '*.*'  vs.  '*.* /MIR'
```

Inconsistency like this is utterly demoralizing...

Answer (score 0):

Powershell doesn't expand $variables when using single quotes.

Use double quotes here:

```
[string]$line = "RoboCopy  $srcPath  $desPath  $option1"
```

And it might make better sense to not use Invoke-Expression

```
 RoboCopy.exe  $srcPath  $desPath  *.* /MIR
```

Should work

Comment: I need the Invoke-Expression since this is actually an interpreter of PowerShell script where the interpreter read a text file of PowerShell script and execute the script line by line

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean.  Explore double quotes on each `[string]$line`  command

Comment: Thanks, Chris. I'll play with it some more